# Why create a temporary constructor when doing Javascript inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototype, google-closure-library

Why does [`goog.inherits`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/15160ce901b70ac9df5e7d25ae4835835738f782/closure_goog_base.js.source.html) from the Google Closure Library look like this:

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

rather than

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new parentCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

What benefit does `tempCtor` provide?

Comment: Both add a useless object on the inheritance chain of instances of *childCtor*. In the first case, that object is an empty function object. In the second, it's a full *parentCtor* instance. So the first can be seen as more efficient (though it creates a new empty function each time, whereas only one is necessary).

Comment: here is a interesting read - http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `parentCtor` had some initialization code, and in the worst case expecting some arguments, then the code might fail unexpectedly. That is why they create a dummy function and inherit from that.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding use of references to literal object instances it is decoupling the prototype of childCtor from the actual instance of parentCtor's prototype by inserting another function instance.

Answer (score 1):

*thefourtheye* pretty much answers the question. The first is seen as a little more efficient, but can be made more efficient if only one temporary constructor is created during initialisation, not one on each invocation of *inherits*:

```
goog.inherits = (function() {
  function tempCtor(){}
  return function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
    tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
    childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
    childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
    childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
  };
}());
```

I doubt that the difference is measurable, it just gives you a warm inner glow to save a couple of CPU cycles and bytes of memory from time to time.